# Is Service Locator pattern supported in .NET Core?

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core, service-locator

Does .net core support the service locator pattern? I realize the option of dependency injection, and that this is considered an anti-pattern, but I want to know if this is potentially supported in .net core?

The .net core documentation seems to say that they support the service locator pattern via injecting IServiceProvider, and then resolving the service with this injected provider. The problem is that this is still dependency injection and doesn't work in all cases.

The other "hack" that I've tried is saving off the created ServiceProvider (either in Configure() or building this in ConfigureServices()). The problem is that I'm saving off the root provider into basically a global variable. As this is the root provider, all scoped services are upgraded to singletons, so it is not a plausible solution.

Here is how it worked in the .net framework:

```cs
var myService =
    (T)GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(T)));
```

Comment: Short answer: **YES**

Comment: Please show us the problem you are trying to solve. Service Locator is a *pattern* (i.e. an abstract definition). Instead, show us an example of where, why, and how you need it (i.e. show the code). Without such example, your question is too broad.

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: If you are in a method and you need access to a service, that service needs to be provided to the method (it cannot be looked up from within the method). The only caveat to this is you could inject the IServiceProvider - so you can locate the service off of the injected instance. This is really such a pain because now you have to clutter up all of your calls with the listing of dependencies - sometimes passing these through multiple calls just to have a call work... and then when you change the dependencies needed, you end up changing your code as well :(